# My Win10 machines can't ping Rapsberry

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi

I have a problem only relative to my Windows 10 machine. I can't reach my Raspberry PI3, although I can see this device from any LAN monitoring tool.

Win 10: 192.168.1.2
Gateway Router: 192.168.1.1
Raspberry :192.168.1.169

**MyLanViewer Report on 2021.05.08  04:18**

Devices (9)

```
MAC Address Last IPv4 Address   Last Host Name by IPv4  Last IPv6 Address   Last Host Name by IPv6  NIC Vendor  Last Time Found First Time Found

00:FF:A7:XX:XX:XX   N/A N/A fe80::c134:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX   N/A N/A 2021.05.08  04:17   2021.05.08  04:04
00:FF:DE:XX:XX:XX   N/A N/A fe80::7573:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX   N/A N/A 2021.05.08  04:17   2021.05.08  04:04
14:DA:E9:XX:XX:XX   192.168.1.2 My-PC   fe80::8977:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX   My-PC   ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.   2021.05.08  04:17   2021.05.08  04:04
3C:37:86::XX:XX:XX  192.168.1.1 DD-WRT  N/A N/A NETGEAR 2021.05.08  04:17   2021.05.08  04:04
78:92:9C::XX:XX:XX  N/A N/A fe80::ed43:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX   N/A Intel Corporate 2021.05.08  04:17   2021.05.08  04:04
B8:27:EB::XX:XX:XX  192.168.1.169   RaspberryPI3    fe80::ba27:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX   N/A Raspberry Pi Foundation 2021.05.08  04:17   2021.05.08  04:04
```

**ping from win10 desktop**

Ping Statistics for 192.168.1.169: Packets: Sent = 20, Received = 0, Lost = 20 (100% lost)

Just added to my routes for eth0 interface manually, but not solved...the same result from wlan interface.

---

will answer your questions globally:
My RPi can ping router, it's wired connected but now can not navigate to internet...maybe n issue with tunnelling interface.
This is my iptables in RPi:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

My Windows PC:

```
Indirizzo rete             Mask          Gateway     Interfaccia Metrica
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
```

Comment: Are you sure the RPi is configured to return pings? What is the netmask setting? Does your router respond to pings?

Comment: I assume this is a headless configuration?

Comment: Check with ifconfig what Wireless address you have on your PI. I connected mine up to my wireless router (same subnet as my wired router) and I can ping my PI from any device on my network.   Did you update your PI to the newest version of whatever Linux you put on it?

Comment: How are the devices connected? Do you have connectivity from the Pi to Windows? From the router to the Pi? Does the Pi have a firewall? Have you tried a network tracing tool like tcpdump or Wireshark? What are the routing tables on Windows and the Pi?

Comment: will answer your questions globally: My RPi can ping router, it's wired connected. This is my iptables in RPi:

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Comment: Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with a fresh reinstallation of raspberrypi OS, but now my win10 resolve rpi hostname with its wlan address, not eth0:

```
Server:  DD-WRT
Address:  192.168.0.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Nome:    raspberrypi.WORKGROUP
Address:  192.168.0.18  ###wlan0 address###
```

I want that its address would be eth0 address 192.168.1.3. The wifi is off on the raspberrypi, I can reach samba shared folder in RPI from win10 machine, but giving its numeric address //192.168.0.3/share not the hostname //raspberrypi/share.